# Maven build project after checkout

Tags: maven, svn, pom.xml

First off, I am new to maven and I don't really understand many of its concepts so my apologies for any noob mistakes.

I am working on a project where I checkout a branch from a local svn repository whose projects are all maven projects. One of those projects has a `pom.xml` file that compiles all other projects into a `project.ear` file when I call `mvn package`.

What I need to do is be able to create an external `pom.xml` file to checkout the branch and afterwards call the `pom.xml` inside one of the recently obtained projects. Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
checkout branch_url checkoutDir=src
mvn src/project-with-pom/pom.xml package
```

I have used the scm plugin to do the checkout (`scm:checkout`), but I can't seem to figure out how to call that inner `pom.xml` file after checkout.

I tried using the invoker plugin but I don't think that's its purpose for it always gives me the following:

> No projects were selected for execution.

## invoker

```
<!-- scm:checkout plugin -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <setupIncludes>
            <setupInclude>${basedir}/src/project-with-pom/pom.xml</setupInclude>
        </setupIncludes>
        <pomIncludes>
            <pomInclude>*/pom.xml</pomInclude>
        </pomIncludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create_ear_file</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have also tried using `scm:bootstrap` but I always get the following error right after the checkout completes:

> This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.

## scm:bootstrap

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>pass</password>
        <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
        <scmVersion>branch_name</scmVersion>
        <scmVersionType>branch</scmVersionType>
        <checkoutDirectory>${basedir}/src</checkoutDirectory>
        <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
        <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
        <goals>package</goals>
        <goalsDirectory>/src/project-with-pom</goalsDirectory>
        <includes>POM.xml</includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have also tried using modules but since the module file doesn't exist it always gives me an error. I tried doing this with profiles but nothing.

Is there a way to do this?

Also, on a side note, is there any way to avoid using plain text for the password for svn?

## EDIT

Guess I wasn't all that clear. I'll try to rephrase it.

My end-goal is to have a clean set of projects pulled and built by a single maven command. If I were to use Subversive and checkout a branch I can use maven to compile a .EAR file from said branch without any problems. But what I want to do is use `scm:checkout` instead of Subversive and then build the project, all in a single maven command.

The execution would be something like:

```
mvn scm:checkout -DcheckoutDirectory=src & mvn package -f src/project-with-pom/pom.xml
```

I tried using a multi-module approach but it seems that maven first builds the child module and then the parent module, thus I get the "child does not exists" error. I need for the parent module to first execute the checkout command and then build the child module that is inside the checkout directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Maven with a different pom file using the `-f` parameter

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html

But actually, I do not fully understand your request (or your project structure): Every Maven project has a `pom.xml`. If there are POMs in the subdirectories, you have a multi-module project. You cannot have a Maven project without POM.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear. What I need to do is first get the files from a local repository and afterwards call a pom file to build the rest of the project. If I try using it as multi-module it gives me a "Child module ... doesn't exist" error. Basically using a single mvn command to get the files and then call another pom file.